# Should a wavefunction in momentum space be normalisable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, momentum, fourier-transform, normalization

Is this a condition that the wavefunction in momentum space should be normalizable? Like we said that a particle has to be between ${-\infty}$ to ${\infty}$. Will the same argument also work for momentum?

Comment: Do you know about Plancherel's theorem?

Comment: @DanielC I just looked it up. I think it is clear from Plancherel theorem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plancherel's theorem is the *mathematical* way of answering this but it assumes you've understood the *physical* meaning of normalisation.

That is, you need the *total* probability of finding the particle (in **whichever** variable) to be $1$, that is:

- finite, to make physical sense;
- non-zero, meaning the particle actually exists.

If I work in real space (in 1D), then my wavefunction is $\psi(x)$ and the normalisation condition is $\int_{\text{all}\,x} |\psi(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x  =1$. Where $|\psi(x)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$ is the probability of finding a particle between positions $x$ and $x+\mathrm{d}x$.

If I work in momentum space (in 1D), then my wavefunction is $\tilde{\psi}(k)$ and the normalisation condition is $\int_{\text{all}\,k} |\tilde{\psi}(k)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}k  =1$. Where $|\tilde{\psi}(k)|^2 \,\mathrm{d}k$ is the probability of finding a particle between momenta $k$ and $k+\mathrm{d}k$.